# Unable to stop Squid3

Tags: ubuntu, squid, docker

When trying to stop `squid3` that is running off a docker image `jpetazzo/squid-in-a-can`, I am unable to stop squid!

```
root@myserver:/# service squid3 stop
[FAIL] Stopping Squid HTTP Proxy 3.x: squid3[....]  Waiting.......................................................................... failed.
failed!
```

Same thing happens when doing `service squid3 restart`.

```
[FAIL] Restarting Squid HTTP Proxy 3.x: squid3[....]  Waiting...........................................................................failed.
. ok
```

Why is this happening?

---

### Updates

**squid.conf** Default *bloated* config file is used.

**cache.log** Nothing seems to be added here on failed `service squid3 restart`

```
...
...
2015/07/01 01:06:17| Logfile: opening log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 01:06:17| Logfile: closing log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 01:06:17| NETDB state saved; 0 entries, 1 msec
2015/07/01 01:48:05| Logfile: opening log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 01:48:05| Logfile: closing log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 01:48:05| NETDB state saved; 0 entries, 0 msec
2015/07/01 02:44:38| Logfile: opening log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 02:44:38| Logfile: closing log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 02:44:38| NETDB state saved; 0 entries, 1 msec
2015/07/01 03:31:53| Logfile: opening log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 03:31:53| Logfile: closing log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 03:31:53| NETDB state saved; 0 entries, 1 msec
2015/07/01 04:49:57| Logfile: opening log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 04:49:57| Logfile: closing log stdio:/var/log/squid3/netdb.state
2015/07/01 04:49:57| NETDB state saved; 0 entries, 2 msec
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a couple of things:

1. (extremely) Big cache
2. Slow Hardware (Disk)
3. Permission-Problem

A few questions:

1. What are your cache-paremters in squid.conf
2. Is there enough RAM? What about swap to disk?

Comment: From a fresh docker container of `jpetazzo/squid-in-a-can`, theres 9.6M free Mem and 4.0G free Swap. The default squid.conf is used. Server has no cache (brand new docker container) and server uses SSD disks so it should be sufficiently fast. I'm running `service stop squid3` as root, does this mean permission problems can be ruled out?

Comment: Unfortuneately i have no expirience with docker. But i use squid for a long time in various configs.

Can you post the output of cache.log at shutdown and the squid.conf?

Comment: Updated the original question with `cache.log` (no new lines added on failed restart/shutdown) and the squid.conf is the default one.

Comment: if the squid is new, did you Create the cache first before trying to start? please provide the squid conf